# Sharepoint Lists - Traffic Light Calculated Formula & Format for Dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to create a Traffic Light system within SharePoint Online (Office 365) using JSON.

The dates should run in accordance to said, Traffic light signal.

What I'm trying to do:

If "Todays Date" is GREATER THAN the [End Date] = RED LIGHT

If "Todays Date" is approaching (or is equal to [3 DAYS away from]) the [END DATE] = YELLOW LIGHT

If "Todays Date" is GREATER than 3 DAYS or more away from [END DATE] = GREEN LIGHT

I have read multiple posts for potential solutions. But haven't found any success. The JSON code below is what I currently have. From what I can tell the last snippet of the code runs successfully `if([$RD] == 'Approaching','','purple')))"` as well as everything else. However the remainder of the `IF` statements aren't (`=if([$RD] == 'No', 'green', if([$RD] == 'Yes', 'red',`.

(RD) Remaining Days Calculated Formula:

```
=TODAY()>[End Date]
```

Format Reference Column

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "=if([$RD] == '', '', '•')",
      "style": {
        "color": "=if([$RD] == 'No', 'green', if([$RD] == 'Yes', 'red', if([$RD] == 'Approaching','','purple')))",
        "font-size": "5em"
      }
    }
```

As a visual aid this is what my Sharepoint List currently looks like.
[image: As a visual aid this is what my Sharepoint List currently looks like.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to show Traffic Light as circle in the output:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "•",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$EndDate]>(@now +259200000), 'Green', if([$EndDate]>@now && [$EndDate]<= (@now +259200000), 'Yellow', 'Red'))",
    "font-size": "5em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

[image]

---

You can try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$EndDate]>(@now +259200000), 'GREEN LIGHT', if([$EndDate]>@now && [$EndDate]<= (@now +259200000), 'YELLOW LIGHT', 'RED LIGHT'))",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$EndDate]>(@now +259200000), 'Green', if([$EndDate]>@now && [$EndDate]<= (@now +259200000), 'Yellow', 'Red'))",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

[image]

Note: In the formula, 86400000 X 3 =259200000

Please refer to [MS Article for Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: This solution works. Thank you! I feel a bit stupid. I should've realized the equation should've been 86400000 X 3 =259200000 instead of just "3" (which I thought automatically converted into days).